# Get Azure application manifest programmatically via API

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365-restapi

Created Application in MicrosoftGraph API

```
Post https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications
```

Is there a way to get the Manifest also using APIs?

Comment: What is the case where "GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/<id>" does not work for you? Is there any specific data about the application that you are expecting?

Comment: it is in a different format, the fields are different. I would like to store the manifest in db as is, so later admin can restore the app without using the api.

Answer (score 2):

The application manifest is nothing more than a GET on the application entity (as Sriram is suggesting).  Please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-application-manifest/ for more details.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I have the reason to get the manifest, it has different property names and I would need to convert the data into the right format to be able to upload it back to azure later manually without using the api.

Comment: What's your scenario that you need to update later manually?  Why not use the API to GET/SET?  I'm not sure that the API below (which is the Azure Portal URL) is the recommended or supported approach for this.

Comment: The manifest is needed so later the admin (not developer) of the tenancy can modify the app via portal.

Comment: Unfortunately the manifest contains some properties that shouldn't be shown, and that accounts for the differences.  We don't have a programmatic way to do this.  The manifest was *intended* to be the same as GET application, but it didn't work out that way.